Dolby 3D multiband notch-filter glasses; could they ever be used with printed materials or OLED displays?
Dolby 3D uses a multiband notch filter over each eye which corresponds to a matching filter on two separate projectors. The transmission curves of each eye are shifted slightly so that the right eye becomes blind to the left image and vice versa. Each eye gets slightly different wavelengths of red, green, and blue than the other eye.
Would it be possible to encode a left/right stereo image pair into a photo print, or into a video file, which would correspond with the notch filters in a pair of these glasses and realize a 3D image?
I'm guessing it wouldn't work, due to the required precision of the notches, which neither a print nor OLED display could likely achieve.
What's your take?


...into a photo print?

I'm guessing that it could not ever be made to work in practice. Dolby-3D relies on using six, narrow-band wavelengths of light. Traditional color printing relies on inks that absorb broad bands of color. For example, in order for the yellow ink to be able to produce a saturated yellow color, it must absorb all of the wavelengths that look blue to your eyes. If it only absorbed a single, narrow band of blue, then the effect would only be a very pale yellow color on the page.
If there was some combination of inks (maybe a lot of different inks) that could cause the print to only reflect in those six narrow wavelength bands, then that would mean that the paper was absorbing most of the ambient light that fell on it. That is to say, the image would look very dark.


...into a video file?

They already do encode it into video files. That's how movies are distributed to theaters anymore. I don't know of any theater in my city that hasn't gone digital. IDK if movie distributors even make film prints these days.
BUT...
It only makes sense to show those video files using video projectors or video monitors that emit those same six narrow wavelength bands. Any projector or monitor that anybody* has in their home right now (as far as I know) only emits three bands of red, green, and blue.

* Not counting any multi-billionaires who may have commercial movie house equivalent screening rooms in their homes or, on board their yachts.

Emissive displays don't need to emit three broad bands. They can recreate the retinal response of many wavelengths using combinations of three very narrow bands. Most do emit slightly broader than very narrow bands because such technology is cheaper to manufacture, but they're nowhere near as broad as the overlapping sensitivity of the three color filters in our camera's CFAs or the 3 types of retinal cones. The peak sensitivities of our retinal cones nor the peak transmissivity of the 3 CFA filters are not the same 3 colors as the target R, G, & B bands that our displays emit, either.

Higher quality and more color accurate displays emit narrower bands of R, G, & B than cheaper ones do. Displays that can reproduce the highest numbers of distinct shades require narrower bands of emission than displays that can't reproduce as many distinctive colors.

@MichaelC, That’s all good, but where can you buy a home video or computer monitor today that is compatible with the Dolby glasses?

My comment was addressing this sentence in your answer: "Any projector or monitor that anybody* has in their home right now (as far as I know) only emits three broader bands of red, green, and blue." That's simply not true. There are many people that have even mid-priced monitors that emit three fairly narrow bands in their homes.

@MichaelC, I removed "broader."

There are also probably still around a few of those 4-band Quattron TVs/monitors from Sharp that emitted RGBY and were priced for the upper middle tier consumer market.

It's the first time I hear about Dolby 3D but your description provides enough information to answer the question.

You necessarily need 6 base colours (with same frequencies as in Dolby 3D) for that, it's absolutely impossible to get that effect with common displays and printers.
Printed image works by absorbing light and if you want to get narrow reflectance band you will necessarily get very dark image. It's significant limitation even if you get necessary inks.

If you are interested there's new 3D display technology which does not require wearing anything before eyes: Acer SpatialLabs View implements it for example. Here is video demonstration (effect cannot be demonstrated but is described verbally): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9Qazw9cVZY

Actually, I have thought of a way that printing could work. It's pretty far fetched, but... If you had six different dyes or coatings that could be applied to the paper, and if each of them absorbed just one narrow band of wavelengths and was transparent to all others, then you could make a print--same way as "process color" works today, but... Here's the tricky part: You would only be able to view the print in a room where the ambient lighting consisted entirely of equal amounts of just those same six narrow bands of color.

@SolomonSlow The same principle applies to LCDs: If you built a display with color filters explicitly for it, you could make this work.  But a normal color display is only going have 3 primaries and a normal video file records in some 3-axis color space, not a spectrograph for every pixel.

@davolfman, Doesn't need a spectrograph for every pixel. Only needs RGB for the left eye, and RGB for the right—six channels in all. And, of course, you'd need a six-color display with "colors" that are compatible with the glasses. Since we already know that they can make projectors with six compatible colors, then the worst-case for building a display would be to make a desktop rear-projection screen. But I'm guessing that they probably could do better than that.

P.S., If we don't have Dolby3D displays in our homes already, then I'd guess that's a marketing problem, and not a technological one. You won't ever have them in any place for which Dolby does not grant a license.

@SolomonSlow I think the assumption of the original question is that you might be able to encode this style of 3d in an existing video format by just sending the right colors.  The only way that would be possible would be if colors were encoded individually, with great precision, instead of as combinations of primaries.  It's a pretty commonly imagined false color system that everything is a single color. Twice as many primaries per pixel would obviously work, and is pretty close to how 3d is encoded when not alternating frames anyway.

Also they're half as bright for the same power, or twice as hot for the same brightness.
